# Acessing third level's states

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to route and access third level's states, but It is not working.
Please, someone may help me showing how to access submenu 'home1'?
I trying to make my code more nasted possible...

My code looks like this example below:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('eventmenu', {
      url: "/event",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "event-menu.html"
    })
    .state('eventmenu.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "home.html"
        }
      }
    })
      .state('eventmenu.home.home1', {
      url: "/home/home1",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "home1.html"
        }
      }
    })
```

You can see the code's example in codepen: [link](https://codepen.io/liamqma/pen/mtBne)

Answer (score 1):

If I had a Dollar for every time i see people have issues with ui-routers view system >.<...

Anyways... Since your trying to replace the same view as the parent state targets, you need to be explicit about it.

```
.state('eventmenu.home.home1', {
  url: "/home1",
  views: {
    'menuContent@eventmenu' :{
      templateUrl: "home1.html"
    }
  }
})
```